# Retrofit model object

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I'm new to Retrofit. I need to create a Parcelable model object for the below JSON query, but can't seem to get it to work. I'm slightly confused given there are two id attributes in the JSON below. Any help would be great.

JSON query

```
   {"id":83542,"page":1,"results":[{"id":"51910979760ee320eb020fc2","author":"Andres Gomez","content":"Interesting film with an exceptional cast, fantastic performances and characterizations. The story, though, is a bit difficult to follow and, in the end, seems to not have a real point.","url":"https://www.themoviedb.org/review/51910979760ee320eb020fc2"},{"id":"520a8d10760ee32c8718e6c2","author":"Travis Bell","content":"Cloud Atlas was a very well made movie but unlike most of the \"simultaneous stories that all come together at the end\" type of movies, this one just didn't. I'm still unclear as to the point of it all.\r\n\r\nAnother issue I had was a general feeling of goofiness. Sure, the Cavendish story was pure comedy but the rest of the stories just didn't feel serious enough to me.\r\n\r\nIt carried my attention for the 172 minutes well enough and it was entertaining. I just expected more of a pay off at the end.\r\n\r\nAll in all, it's definitely worth seeing but I still haven't made up my mind if I truly liked it or not. What did you think?","url":"https://www.themoviedb.org/review/520a8d10760ee32c8718e6c2"}],"total_pages":1,"total_results":2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following model classes for your json:

```
public class Example {
   int id;
   int page;
   List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
   int total_pages;
   int total_results;
}

public class Result {
   String id;
   String author;
   String content;
   String url;
}
```

If you want to convert your JSON to POJO'S as above use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to do this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @pratt, appreciate it

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, then please accept this answer.